# Create a dictionary containing four lambda functions square, cube, squareroot, multiply by 2

Tags: python-3.x

Create a dictionary containing four lambda functions square, cube, squareroot, multiply by 2.

E.g. dict = {'Square': function for squaring, 'Cube': function for cube, 'Squareroot': function for squareroot, 'Double': function for double} and so on

Pass the values (input from the user) to the functions in the dictionary respectively. Then add the outputs of each function and print it.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
def addi(n):
    d = { 'Square': lambda a : a**2, 
         'Cube': lambda a : a**3, 
         'Squareroot': lambda a : a**(1/2), 
         'Double': lambda a : a*2}
    sum = 0
    for key in d.keys():
        sum += d[key](n)
    return sum
    
print(addi(5))
```